# Office 365 API programmatic authentication

Tags: api, authentication, office365

I am pretty new to the Office 365 API- I am looking to authenticate programmatically but the examples I have been testing with require going through the login page.  Is this possible and if so would someone be able to point me to some examples (I am mostly going to be using this for the calendar).  Thanks.

Comment: Asking for code/software/documentation/examples/etc.. is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two basic authentication flow of OAuth2.0 for Azure AD.

The first is **Authorization Code Grant Flow** which used to access to web APIs by native clients and websites in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). In this flow, the user delegates access to a client application.

The second is **Client Credentials Grant Flow** which permits a web service (a confidential client) to use its own credentials to authenticate when calling another web service, instead of impersonating a user. In this scenario, the client is typically a middle-tier web service, a daemon service, or web site.

Here is an example that using the **Client Credentials Grant Flow** to get the messages from specific user for your reference:

```
    string clientId = "";
    string clientsecret = "";
    string tenant = "yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com";

    var authUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tenant+"/oauth2/token";
    var RESOURCE_URL = "https://outlook.office.com";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authUri);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientsecret);
    var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE_URL, credential).Result;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + result.AccessToken);


     var response = client.GetAsync("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/user1@yourdomain.onmicrosoft/messages").Result;

    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

And to use the Office 365 REST API, we need to register the app first. You can refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually) for the detail.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work - everything that I've read suggests that you need to use an X.509 certificate in the client credential flow. [See this page for more info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/)

Comment: The client credential flow support two ways. One is using the secret and the other is using the certificate.

Comment: @FeiXue - I think the authorization code grant type would also show up the login screen where the user needs to enter his/her credentials. It later shows a authorization page that the user needs to accept in order to proceed further. Wouldn't the resource credential grant type be beneficial here where the credentials are passed in the api call as request parameters?